# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createSnapshot')

Tags: webpack, next.js, storybook, postcss, sass-loader

I was trying to integrate sass in storybook with nextjs.

Running `npm run dev` in the terminal would successfully read the sass files and everything seems normal but when it comes to running `npm run storybook`, I get this error. I have already tried uninstalling the node_modules and package-lock.json, then running `npm run install`, but the error is still there.

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "samahan-website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.7.0",
    "@storybook/addon-postcss": "^2.0.0",
    "@storybook/preset-scss": "^1.0.3",
    "next": "12.1.6",
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.10",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.11",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "eslint": "8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.6",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.5.11",
    "sass": "^1.51.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.1",
    "storybook-addon-next": "^1.6.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.72.1"
  }
}
```

while this is the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createSnapshot')
    at X:\Samahan\samahan-website\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\lib\webpack5\file-watcher-api.js:13:36
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.createSnapshot (X:\Samahan\samahan-website\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\lib\webpack5\file-watcher-api.js:12:10)
    at X:\Samahan\samahan-website\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\lib\cached-child-compiler.js:219:3
```

Comment: did you add env variables needed?